# Extension Galois field, multiplication of elements

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Consider the extension field $GF(2^4)$ and the primitive polynomial $P(x)=x^4+x^3+1$. How would I find the result of multiplication of elements $1011$ and $1100$?

My work:

$1011$ corresponds to $\{1x^3 + 0x^2 + 1x^1 + 1x^0\} = x^3 + x + 1$

$1100$ corresponds to $\{1x^3 + 1x^2 + 0x^1 + 0x^0\} = x^3 + x^2$

Multiplying:
$(x^3 + x + 1 ) * ( x^3 + x^2 )\\ 
= x^6 + x^ 5 + x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2\\
= x^2(x^3+1) + x(x^3+1) + (x^3+ 1) + 2x^3 + x^2\\
= x^5 +  x^2 + x^4 + x + x^3 + 1 + 2x^3 + x^2 \\
= x(x^3 + 1) +x^2 + (x^3 + 1) + x + x^3 + 1 + 2x^3 + x^2 \\
= x^4 + x + x^2 + x^3 + 1 + x + x^3 + 1 + 2x^3 + x^2 \\
= (x^3 +1) + x^2 + x^3 + 1 + x + x^3 + 1 + 2x^3 + x^2 \\
= 5x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 3
= x^3 + x + 3 \\
 $

Binary representation = 1011

But, I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Take the remainder modulo $P(x)$, since $P(x)\equiv 0$.

Comment: So would it be x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 at the end since we are taking modulo of 2 as we go?

Comment: No, it would not. What about my comment makes you think that?

Comment: You do need to calculate the product modulo two, but you also need to calculate it modulo $P(x)$. Hint: Modulo $P(x)$ you have $x^4\equiv x^3+1$, do you see why? Consequently you also have $x^5\equiv x(x^3+1)$ and $x^6\equiv x^2(x^3+1)$. Keep reducing the product modulo $P(x)$ until you are left with something that has degree $<4$. In other words, do polynomial long division by $P(x)$ and take the remainder.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for the recommendation. I have updated my solution. Please let me know if this is correct.

Comment: You should reduce modulo 2. So it would be $x^3+x+1$

Comment: @ndhanson3 Youre absolutely right. I just forgot to type that. Will fix it. Thanks!

Comment: It is much, much easier to divide $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^2$ (the $2x^3$ is equal to $0x^3$) by $P(x)$. If $f(x)=P(x)q(x)+r(x)$, then $f(x)\equiv r(x)\pmod{P(x)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in binary, using long hand (carryless - xor instead of add) multiplication and (borrowless - xor instead of subtract) division:

Multiply

```
    1011
    1100
    ----
    0000
   0000
  1011
 1011
 -------
 1110100  == x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2
```

Divide

```
            101
      ---------
11001 | 1110100
        11001
        -----
         01000
         00000
         -----
          10000
          11001
          -----
           1001   == x^3 + 1
```

---

Or following the method in the original question, noting that x^i + x^i == 0:

$(x^3 + x + 1 ) * ( x^3 + x^2 )\\ 
= (x^6 + x^4 + x^3) + (x^5 + x^3 + x^2) \\
= x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 \\
= x^2(x^3 + 1) + x(x^3 + 1) + (x^3 + 1) + x^2 \\
= (x^5 + x^2) + (x^4 + x) + x^3 + 1 + x^2 \\
= x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 \\
= x(x^3 + 1) + (x^3 + 1) + x^3 + x + 1 \\
= (x^4 + x) + (x^3 + 1) + x^3 + x + 1 \\
= x^4 \\
= x^3 + 1
$